Previous owners put insulation over the foundation. Is it alright to remove this?
We live in southwest Ontario, winters don't get too cold here and there's already insulation on the inside.
Would we be best to put siding over this or should we just remove it? Rodents have been living in the gaps between the foundation and the foam.
Also wondering is there's an attractive way to cover the foundation if we do remove it.
Thanks in advance


You'd be better served to put it on correctly, (no gaps between the foundation and foam) including a stucco finish coat over it which prevents sun damage and rodent incursion (if done properly.)
But if you insist on just removing it, you can stucco the foundation itself.

+1 for installing it correctly. Southwestern Ontario is cold enough that you're certainly losing heat through the foundation walls. Utility bills aren't decreasing any time soon.
